# How to make ViewHolder listen to screen orientation change?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, orientation, android-viewholder

I want to notify all `ViewHolder` of `RecyclerView` when the screen orientation is changed. I can notify the `ViewHolder` that are on screen. But for the ones that are out of screen I don't know how to notify them. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your activity to get the orientation changing :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //PORTRAIT MODE
        adapter.screenChanged("PORTRAIT");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //LANDSCAPE MODE
        adapter.screenChanged("LANDSCAPE");
    }
}
```

add this to your adapter

```
 public void screenChanged(String orientation){
        if (orientation.equals("PORTRAIT")){
            //code
        }else{
            //code
        }
    }
```

Comment: The main question is: how to notify all `ViewHolder` include the ones that are out of screen

Comment: what you mean by out of the screen

Comment: I mean, for example: we have 6 ViewHolder objects. 4 of them are on the screen (we have 4 items on screen). And 2 of them are not displayed on screen

Comment: so you need to to notify them at the moment when they shows up

Answer (score 0):

You can get orientation by using getResources() in your Adapter/ViewHolder. Depending on how you get it, the ViewHolder View passed to the constructor can give you just that:

```
private HeaderViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    int mOrientation = itemView.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
}
```

or through the onCreateViewHolder:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    Context mContext = viewGroup.getContext();
    int mOrientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    ...
}
```

This value should change when the screen is rotated.